# How does "te savoir (quelque part / à ... / parmi ...)" compare to other synonyms?

Tags: sens, usage

> Chouette de te **savoir** parmi nous à nouveau.

I just heard one of my friends say this. Given the context (where I just got back  to my old stomping ground), I can safely assume that "savoir" is used here in the sense of "t'**avoir** parmi nous à nouveau", "te **retrouver**/**revoir** parmi nous".

But how does  "savoir" compare to these other variants? A couple of usage examples wouldn’t go amiss, either.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't discard *savoir*. *Être* (or a similar verb) is implicit here, the meaning being:

> Chouette de te savoir [être] parmi nous à nouveau.
>
> Chouette de savoir que tu es à nouveau parmi nous.

so the meaning is

> Glad to know you are among us again.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean by "discard" here. :)

Comment: *To get rid of*. You remove it from your interpretation (*t'avoir*, *te retrouver*).